# Multiple software serial ports

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm having a bit of trouble with the Arduino 1.0.5 SoftwareSerial library. I understand that ideally, I should be using a Mega here, but unfortunately I need to make do with an Uno R3.

I understand that it is possible to use multiple SoftSerial ports, provided that you switch between the two using `Soft1.listen();` etc. but I seem to be having troubles with this.

If I run the below sketch for example:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial Soft1(3,2);
SoftwareSerial Soft2(5,4);

void setup()
{
    Soft2.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
    Soft2.print("Test");
    delay(1000);
}
```

I get exactly what I would expect - The word 'Test' printed every second. Now, if I replace `Soft2.begin` with `Soft1.begin` I get nothing. Adding `Soft1.listen();` either before the 'print', or even before the 'begin' makes no difference. I need to read/write from one port, and write only to the second port, but it would appear that the SoftwareSerial library make up its mind on which port to use when they are declared rather during the program.

Has anybody ever used multiple SoftwareSerial ports successfully?

EDIT:

Just some more information for folks, if I swap the order of the software serial declarations, the live/dead ports reverse, so it really does appear to be something around that point. Just for testings sake, I've tried not starting either port until it is needed and doing the following:

```
void loop() {
    Soft2.begin(9600);
    Soft2.print("test2");
    Soft2.end();
    delay(1000); // For stability/to alleviate timing issues, whatever.
    Soft1.begin(9600);
    Soft1.print("test1");
    Soft1.end();
}
```

But to no avail. I'm just seeing the 'test2' output.

Cheers,
Alex.

Comment: Did you forget to rewire the cable to the other pins used by Soft1?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Both of these ports are permanently connected. I'm using Soft1 to read data from a GPS module via polling rather than reading automatic updates and Soft2 to write that data to an OpenLog.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot find a solution to this, and as such, I've opted to use just a single SoftwareSerial port, and tied this to a dual 4:1 multiplexer (74HC4052 for those interested) using 2 digital pins as the logical select (2 bit binary). This isn't ideal, but I think with the nature of the project this would be the safest option.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry that this answer is so long after the initial post. I have actually faced this problem before. I had connected both a screen and an RFBee to one arduino. I then sent serial communication from my computer to the first arduino with a first RFBee connected to it. This arduino then sent the information to the second arduino through the RFBee. The second arduino then sent the data to the screen and returned a statement through the RFBee to the first arduino which returned to the computer saying it had been sent. For some reason the message would not send back to the first arduino.  It was something about having to select which serial port was currently open before reading from it. If you put a SoftX.listen(); before you use it, it should work fine. If you need a better explanation, there's one at http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/TwoPortReceive Hope this was of some help. Also, don't have the SoftX.begin(); statement in loop.  Could cause problems.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This project had to be parked due to various personal issues, however, as luck would have it, I've just picked it back up again. I'll try your suggestion and see if I can get some joy out of the old beast.